# Dozer# Can Dozer supports Polymorphism?

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

Please see following structure of my SourceClass and DestinationClass.

```
public class SourceClass {

    // Some Mapping Goes here
    protected SomeObject someObject;

    public static class SomeObject {
        // Some Mapping Goes here for all parameters
        protected String param1;
        protected String param2;
        protected String param3;
        protected String param4;
        protected String param5;
        protected String param6;
        protected String param7;
        protected String param8;
        protected String param9;
        protected String param10;
    }
}


public class DestinationClass {
    protected MyObject myObject;
}

public class MyObject {
    protected String param1;
    protected String param2;
    protected String param3;
}

public class ChildClass1 extends MyObject {
    String param8;
    String param9;
    String param10;
}

public class ChildClass2 extends ChildClass1 {
    protected String param4;
    protected String param5;
    protected String param6;
    protected String param7;
}
```

I am setting **ChildClass2** object in **MyObject** in my application. As you can see that ChildClass2 has all 10 parameters.

Is there any way to map this type of structure in Dozer ?

Comment: Did you try it? I don't know Dozer too well but AFAIK it should be able to handle those cases (you might need getters/setters but I'm not sure here).

Comment: I have tried it. If I use @Mapping("myObject") at SomeObject in SourceClass then It will give me exception that param4 is not there in MyObject.I think there should some way to do this.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to get values from `SomeObject` to `MyObject` (it not then please post your mapping) which can't work since instances of `MyObject` don't have those paramaters (only instances of `ChildClass2` have). You might need to add additional mapping information or some "ignore unknown properties" setting to handle cases that should copy into `MyObject` or `ChildClass1` only.

Comment: Exactly. but Unfortunately I don't know that additional mapping.

Comment: What I meant is a mapping from `SomeObject` to `MyObject` as well as one from `SomeObject` to `ChildClass1` etc. - and you might have to list individual properties.

Comment: Thanks. Previously i was trying to convert SourceClass to DestinationClass. 
I just tried this : Taking someObject and convert it in ChildClass2. and then assign this ChildClass2 to myObject in DestinationClass. This solved my problem. 
But still looking for some annotation or additional mapping which can optimize this solution.